# constant speed elevator light beam paradox

Tags: visible-light

I can't get my head around this problem.  Suppose there is an elevator moving up at a constant speed relative to an observer outside of the elevator, far away from any gravitational effects. Suppose a laser gun with a 1 meter long narrow barrel with a diameter of .10 cm emits a laser beam from one side of the elevator's wall, parallel to the floor of the elevator. A spot of light should appear on the opposite wall just below the line of sight of the laser gun as viewed from the outside observer.   But the observer inside the elevator would see the spot appear exactly opposite of the barrel. How is this paradox resolved?

Comment: While I am lacking the complete picture of how your elevator (why does it have to be an elevator if there is no gravity?) is oriented form the viewpoint of the external observer, I believe to remember that the outside observer will see the elevator rotated by a small angle, which should be just enough to resolve the "paradox".

Comment: From the outside observer, the beam of light does *not* fall below the line of sight. It falls exactly where one would naively expect.

Comment: It's to do with the relativity of simultaneity. The spot on the opposite that an observer in the elevator sees as being opposite the laser when it is fired by an observer in the elevator is not the same spot that the outside observer sees as being opposite the laser when it is fired.

Answer (score 1):

The spot of light isn't below the line of sight of the laser gun, and the outside observer shouldn't expect that to be the case.

The laser gun is attached to the elevator wall, so according to the outside observer, the momentum of photons as they come out of the laser gun must have a non-zero upward component, or else conservation of momentum would be violated.  From the outside observer's perspective, the upward component of the photon's momentum is just enough to make the photon land on the line of sight of the laser gun as of when the photon lands.

Comment: But if an outside observer saw an upward momentum added to the photons emerging from the barrel, then with respect to the outside observer, the light's total speed would be greater than c, because it would travel the path of the hypotenuse of a right triangle, with the horizontal leg going at speed c and the upper vertical leg going at its speed due to the upward momentum of the photon. This would violate the second postulate of special relativity which states the speed of light is constant for all inertial observers regardless of the motion of the source of light.

Comment: @user55465 No, according to the outside observer, the horizontal component of the beam's velocity is less than c, such that the beam's speed is still c.

Answer (score 0):

If the elevator is going up rather fast, the light from the back of the elevator takes longer to reach the observer than the light from the front.

This means that I see the back of the elevator at an "earlier time" - put differently, it looks to be a bit lower. The angle by which it appears to be lower is given by the velocity of the elevator divided by the velocity of light.

Exactly the same angle by which you expect the beam to be low. So yes - the beam will appear angled, but it will hit a "low" target. All is well.